# Creating an array to display using blade with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I create the following array in my controller:

```
$appointmentLocation = compact("address1", "address2");

return view('appointments.show')->with(['appointmentLocation' => $appointmentLocation]);
```

I would like to display it like so using blade in my view:

```
{{ $appointmentLocation->address1 }}
```

but I get : `Trying to get property of non-object`

When I `dd($appointmentLocation);`

I get

```
array:2 [▼
"address1" => "101 York st."
"address2" => "Suite 1"
]
```

Do you know what's missing so I can display using `{{ $appointmentLocation->address1 }}`?

Comment: An array isn't an object, so you can't access its fields with object notation. You either have to use `{{ $appointmentLocation['address1'] }}`, or you have to type-cast it to an object: `with(['appointmentLocation' => (object) $appointmentLocation]);`

Comment: I keep learning everyday. Thanks @samlev